# How to refresh @Html.ValidationMessageFor when @Html.TextBoxFor is updated by jQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing web application by ASP.NET-MVC.

Model:

```
[Display(Name = "REGISTERED ADDRESS")]
[StringLength(255)]
public string ADDRESS { get; set; }
```

Html:

```
@Html.TextBox("textBoxFillToAnothertextBox", null, new { id = "textBoxFillToAnothertextBox", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Fill in to apply for textBoxAddress" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ADDRESS, new { id = "textBoxAddress" + i, @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ADDRESS, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

jQuery:

```
$('#textBoxFillToAnothertextBox').on('keyup change', function () {
    $('#textBoxAddress').val($('#textBoxFillToAnothertextBox').val());
});
```

Case 1: I fill text to "textBoxAddress". The text length is more than 255 and then the "ValidationMessage of Address" is show up as normal.

Case 2: I fill text to "textBoxFillToAnothertextBox" that set to "textBoxAddress" by jQuery. The text length is more than 255 and then the "ValidationMessage of Address" isn't show up.

Could someone help to suggested me in case 2, please?

Comment: `ValidationMessageFor` used to validate input controls created by HTML helper in server-side. If you want to check textbox length which value modified in client-side, use 
 `$('#textBoxAddress').val().length` and put it inside jQuery validator settings.

Comment: Set `maxlength` on the input. Note a user can manipulate this from browser dev tools but most won't

Comment: JQuery validation is triggered initially on the `blur()` event and thereafter on the `.keyup()` event, so you need to trigger that event on the other textbox (e.g. `$('#textBoxAddress').trigger('keyup');`). But what is the point of this - why copy the text from one textbox to another?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, understand and thank you.

Comment: @charlietfl, understand and thank you.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I created dynamic web application that including textBoxAddress1, textBoxAddress2 ... textBoxAddressN per company branch from database. And then I add textBoxFillToAnothertextBox for apply text to another. So user can update data for each company branch by fill in textBoxAddressX or update data for all by fill in textBoxFillToAnothertextBox. Note: This is example, Address may different, but phone isn't for many company branch.

Comment: That is typically done by using a checkbox (i.e check it if same address as above)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, understand and thank you. Currently I use your concept e.g. $('#textBoxAddress').trigger('keyup'); but I use focus() and then it's work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I use concept from @StephenMuecke.

jQuery:

```
$('#textBoxFillToAnothertextBox').on('keyup change', function () {
    $('#textBoxAddress').val($('#textBoxFillToAnothertextBox').val());
    $('#textBoxAddress').focus();
    $('#textBoxFillToAnothertextBox').focus();
});
```

It's work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use `maxlength` attributes:

```
 @Html.TextBox("textBoxFillToAnothertextBox", null, new { id = "textBoxFillToAnothertextBox",maxlength = 250 , @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Fill in to apply for textBoxAddress" })
```

Or

```
$('#textBoxFillToAnothertextBox').on('keyup change', function() {
    if ($('#textBoxFillToAnothertextBox').val().length > 250) {
        $('#ADDRESS').text('error message');
    } else {
        $('#textBoxAddress').val($('#textBoxFillToAnothertextBox').val());
    }
});
```